# A random Debug came up in my package.json in visual studio that I can't get rid of

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, jestjs, enzyme, visual-studio-debugging

A random Debug statement came up in my package.json and I have no idea how to get rid of it, I don't even know how it got added

[image: Random Debug]

How can I get rid of it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62368407/836330 for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a code lens provided by one of your extensions. You can either disable all code lenses with the `editor.codeLens` setting or figure out which extension is doing this and either disable the extension or just its lens (if it provides a setting).

Comment: The only things I've installed recently are `react-test-renderer`, `enzyme`, `enzyme-adapter-react-16`, and `raf`.  The only files add are a tests/setupTest.js file and a jest.config.json file.  Those are the only extensions I've used which are similar to ones I've had already.  Do you think one of the installs could have caused it?

Comment: Or is it because visual studio code just updated? I could disable `editor.codeLens` but was hoping I could source where it came from.

Comment: Those are JS packages, not VSCode extensions. You can see VSCode extensions in the sidebar, or by running the `View: Show Extensions` command.

Answer (score 1):

There is a specific feature to change for this problem.

Go to your settings, search for "codelens", you'll get multiple results.

Look for "Debug > Javascript > Codelens: Npm Scripts" and change it to never.

[settings with debug issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dkMw.png)