# How to disable “Debug” from showing in package.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, package.json, vscode-debugger, npm-scripts

How to disable the outlined "Debug" tip from showing up in package.json above the `scripts` section:

[image]

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The setting is

```
  "debug.javascript.codelens.npmScripts": "never",
```

[image: codelensDebug]

Since it appears as part of the `scripts` section of the package.json I searched for `scripts` in the `Settings` and it was the second entry.

Comment: Before disabling it, what's its purpose?

Comment: @Jacques Its for [Debuggin NPM Scripts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug#easy-npm-script-debugging)

Comment: Hello, my VSCODE suddenly inserted these "debug flags" on my package.json files in my projects yesterday (3/9/21).  I didn't THINK that I updated anything and it WAS working just fine.  @baburao could you think of any reason why this is happening.  As a side effect it is also  stopping my webpack-dev-server from running properly it would seem, as the script is called from the package.json file.  and the dbug flag is being placed in the same exact location every time, above the "scripts" key (same as the OP).

Comment: any idea why it is being triggered in my electron package json? the "error" reads "The term 'run' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."