# How can I remove VS code debugger?

Tags: react-native, debugging, visual-studio-code

Im developing React Native app with Visual Studio Code now,
but something like a debugger, I dont know what is called, appeared in code somehow.

I think this is a function of VS code.
I want to remove debugger from my package.json,
but I can't search solutions because I don't know what it is called..

this debuger appeared

[image: this debuger appeared]

when I press this, search window appear

[image]

Someone know how can I remove this?
Thank you your answers!

***my env***
VS Code: v1.47.2
Macbook Pro
OS:Catalina 10.15.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible duplicate: [How to disable `Debug` from showing in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62358131/how-to-disable-debug-from-showing-in-package-json)

To remove (or "delete") the debugger open the VSCode settings file and add or modify this line:

```
 "debug.javascript.codelens.npmScripts": "never",
```

or

[image]

Anyway, that is just a function for you to quickly launch the debugging session. Nothing added to your code.

When you press "debug", because you don't specify which script to run, VSCode shows you a list of options for you to choose. Use the up and down buttons to select.

If you hover your mouse a script, a small "tooltips" appear, click on it to run the script under the mouse.

[image]

In this picture, if I click `Run Script`, the terminal windows will run `npm run compile`

Comment: Don't want to downvote, because it's valuable information to new users, but it would be good to at least address the main question of `How can I remove VS code debugger?`, in my opinion anyways

Comment: I think OP is thinking VSCode adds something to the code, therefor asking for a way to "remove" it. Also, OP don't familiar with the VSCode dialogue box, as he misunderstands it with a search box. So I assumed OP is new to vscode.

Comment: It technically is adding something to the [editor] code. I'm not saying your answer isn't helpful, it just doesn't address the question. They want to remove it, and there is a way to do so

Comment: thank you your answer!
Sorry for my bad asking, Im very new to VS code. 
The reason that I said I want to remove is , if I build up my react-native app with expo, command expo start,
Error happens..
Expo open browser and expo says "Error Loading DebugTools".
before yesterday, I never see this error, But debug function appeared, Expo start showing error..

I did run app from small tooltips you told me, app build with no problem.
Actually I really want to remove it but my heavy problem disappeard.
Anyway Thanks!

Comment: By the way,
is there some way to remove it?
(Im saying no to remove from VS CODE, I just want to disappear it)
Or this is always appear everyone's code?

Comment: @Odayan you can review the comment i posted on your question. This question is essentially a duplicate

Comment: @Odayan I think something wrong with the code itself, not the vscode. You can try to run your react-native app from a command prompt without vscode. Otherwise, you can always ask a new question.

Comment: @Tuan
I could understand what you advised!

I edit VS code setting, script debugger => never
I could make debugger disabled!!

Thank you so much!

Comment: This answer is valuable. BTW, there is another option need to be turned off, `Jest: Enable Code Lens`. Only this is OFF, that `Debug` can be gone.