# How can I disable the "Run Script" and "Debug Script" hover tooltips from showing for my package.json scripts?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I disable `Run Script` and `Debug Script` from showing in package.json?

[image]

I saw a similar issue but couldn't resolve it.
[visual studio code - How to disable 'Debug' from showing in package.json - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62358131/how-to-disable-debug-from-showing-in-package-json)

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings):

```json
"npm.scriptHover": false
```

The setting's description:

> Display hover with 'Run' and 'Debug' commands for scripts.