# How to get rid of 'Run script/Debug script' VS Code popup for scripts when hovering in package.json?

Tags: visual-studio-code, package.json

When editing quickly in the package.json it's easy to accidentally hit a popup that VS Code recently seems to have introduced to start a debugger or execute a script.
Working fast this is very unwanted behaviour for me as it executes stuff I don't like to be executed with all problems involved.

[image]

I've searched everywhere on how to turn this off, but can't find anything on this feature.

How to turn this feature off so we don't get these 'Run script' and 'Debug script' popups no more?

Comment: Looking at this commit https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/73b72464b3f71db7ac3b763f37e84769bd411a7b and the relevant issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/73b72464b3f71db7ac3b763f37e84769bd411a7b I don't think there is a setting to turn off those hovers.  Other than to disable all hovers or increase their delay.

Comment: Thanks. Just added a feature request to add a setting to turn this behaviour off: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/155377

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/66218667/11107541

Answer (score 2):

There is a new commit that adds a setting to disable these `Run Script | Debug Script` hover links, see [Add option to disable script hovers in package.json files](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/21504708043941c1e9e45b7d0892a9a8a03470d7).

```
"Display hover with 'Run' and 'Debug' commands for scripts."
npm.scriptHover
```

defaults to `true`.

I don't think it'll hit Stable until v1.71 early September 2022.  But Insiders soon.

Comment: Confirmed: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/155377 has been marked as "insiders-released".

Comment: interestingly, someone asked about this even earlier than this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66218667/11107541 (and that Q&A is more highly upvoted than this one)