# In VS Code, how can I enable "run | debug" codelenses for Java main functions?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

[run | debug in top of line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbxR4.png)

How to display 'run | debug' as in the picture above? it's not showing on my VS Code like this. I have also checked the settings but didn't find. I did 'run debug' in other ways and it still did not appear in the line.

Comment: related if anyone accidentally stumbles here looking for NPM package.json `scripts` related things: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66218667/11107541 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/62358131/11107541.

Comment: You need to install [Extension Pack for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack).       https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure what you're looking for is the [`vscjava.vscode-java-debug`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-debug) extension. It contributes codelenses for run and debug. It has a `java.debug.settings.enableRunDebugCodeLens` setting that defaults to `true`. Related source code is in [`src/debugCodeLensProvider.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-debug/blob/main/src/debugCodeLensProvider.ts).