# Why is VSCODE placing a debug flag above my scripts key in ALL my package.json files?

Tags: visual-studio-code, webpack-dev-server

My VSCODE suddenly inserted these "debug flags" on my package.json files in my projects yesterday (3/9/21). I didn't THINK that I updated anything and it WAS working just fine (no debug flags). Why is this is happening?

If I delete my scripts key, the debug flag disappear.

[image]

Comment: Did you try the fix at https://stackoverflow.com/a/62368407/836330 that you commented at?

Comment: @Mark I did, and it did stop it, but I was wondering how something like this could just "pop-up" out of nowhere.  I read somewhere about VSCODE allowing downloading of new features without the user knowing.