# How do I remove this Debug Symbol from my code?

Tags: javascript, json, debugging, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, this debug symbol appeared in my code (json file). It stops me from running my code. I've tried closing the tab, restarting visual studio code, I just can't get rid of it.

Here is the picture of the debug symbol in my code

[image]

Comment: that is just a VSCode feature, to run the debugger from the package.json

Comment: Check Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62358131/how-to-disable-debug-from-showing-in-package-json