# What is this extra line/area injected in VSCode called? And can I make an exension to create them?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I see this extra line or area injected at a few places in VSCode. I'm thinking about a few ideas to use those areas to enhance my extension: add extra commands or information to code.

I would like to know what is it called? Is there any API for accessing it from an extension?

The extra line/area injected in VSCode

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62337643/a-random-debug-came-up-in-my-package-json-in-visual-studio-that-i-cant-get-rid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a CodeLens.

Here is a bit more from the VSCode blog - https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/02/12/code-lens-roundup

And from the documentation - https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/programmatic-language-features#codelens-show-actionable-context-information-within-source-code